# Will CKAN be the best solution for a portal like asiapacificenergy.org?

Tags: web, ckan

Will CKAN be the best solution for a portal like asiapacificenergy.org?

If yes, can you provide an estimate of how much effort, time and developers would be required?

- Any tips or best practices you can share for an inexperienced team? Any pitfalls to avoid?

Thank you very much.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to say. Depends exactly what you want to do exactly.

From ckan.org:

*CKAN, the world’s leading Open Source data portal platform CKAN is a powerful data management system that makes data accessible – by providing tools to streamline publishing, sharing, finding and using data.*

CKAN is like wordpress but instead of blog posts its datasets. It helps manage and inventory datasets for an organization. It has other cool and powerful features too but that site you mentioned reminds me of ArcGIS kind of. There is also Socrata or many other vendor offerings. I prefer CKAN though.

There is a demo site (demo.ckan.org) you can play with, add and remove stuff from, etc to get a feel for it.

They have decent documentation as well that you can follow https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/user-guide.html . You could setup a local version to get a feel for how hard or easy it is.  https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html

I'd say you need someone with python and server experience to get you setup and then basic usage and administration can be delegated. But it can be learnt.

Gov.uk uses ckan for their data catalogue and have some helpful docs available as well. https://docs.publishing.service.gov.uk/manual/data-gov-uk-supporting-ckan.html